# A normal positive linear functional whose support is 1

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a W*-algebra with unit $1$.

Q1)  Does there exist a normal positive linear functional $\phi$ on $M$ whose support is 1?

Q2) We know that there is a unique central projection $z$ in $M^{**}$ by which every bounded linear functional is decomposed to a normal and singular part:
$$M^*=
\underbrace{zM^*}_{=M_*}\oplus^{\ell^1}(1-z)M^*$$
 True or false: $1\le z$  ?!

Comment: Your first question is standard. You are asking if $M$ has a faithful normal state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your first question let $M=\ell_\infty(\Gamma)$ where $\Gamma$ is uncountable. Certainly, $M_*=\ell_1(\Gamma)$ and each element in $M_*$ is countably supported.

I am not quite sure what is the second question about. You want a projection dominating the unit?

Comment: Thanks for the first one. As for the second one: I mean the unit of $M$ is majorized by the central projection which is described in Q2).

Comment: @AliBagheri, isn't the unit of $M$ also the unit of $M^{**}$?

Comment: oh my god. Yes, you are right.